# How to force python use TLS1.2, not TLS1.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I need to force python make an https request with maximum TLS version set to 1.2 instead of 1.3 and I just can`t.

I`m checking what parameters are advertised by client side by this json - https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check

Platform: **Win10**

Tried several things like:

```
class TLSv1_2HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1
        ssl_context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
        ssl_context.options = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3
        
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3,
            ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

or

```
class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_options = ssl_options
        super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
                                        ssl_context=ctx,
                                        **pool_kwargs)
```

...and it does not work - it still uses TLS1.3 ignoring my setup.
I`m using it like this:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', TlsAdapter())
req = requests.Request('GET','https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check')
prepped = req.prepare()
r = s.send(prepped,
    verify=False,
    proxies=proxies,
    allow_redirects=False
)
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
print(r.json())
```

and it gives me followed credentials:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
{'given_cipher_suites': ['TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV'],
'ephemeral_keys_supported': True,
'session_ticket_supported': True,
'tls_compression_supported': False,
'unknown_cipher_suite_supported': False,
'beast_vuln': False,
'able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting': False,
'insecure_cipher_suites': {},
'tls_version': 'TLS 1.3',
'rating': 'Probably Okay'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using an "or" (the pipe |) when specifing the ssl_context.options and ssl_version. Changing that "or" by an "and" operator ( | --> & ) should work. Here is a tested example:

```py
class TLSv1_2HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1
        ssl_context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
        ssl_context.options = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS & ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3
        
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS & ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3,
            ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

## Update

This should also work using just ssl_context, like this:

```py
class TLSv1_2HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1
        ssl_context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
        ssl_context.options = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS & ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3
        
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_context=ssl_context)
```